# ROS2 parameters file and launch argument override

Tags: ros2, foxy, launch

I am using ROS2 foxy. I would like to launch a node with a set of default parameters in a .yaml file and add support for launch argument to override such parameters.

Default parameters:

```yaml
/imu:
    ros__parameters:
        
        spi_dev: "/dev/spidev0.0"
        output_rate: 200.0 # Hz
        # more params here
```

I tried the following but does not work, what am I missing?
I fear that the parameters passed from launch arguments are not in the node namespace but global, thus are not picked up.

```py
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration

package_name = 'my_sensors'
param_name =  'my_default_params.yaml'

def generate_launch_description():

    rate_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        name='rate',
        default_value="100",
        description="the sensor output data rate")

    device_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        name='device',
        default_value="/dev/spidev0.0",
        description="the imu spi device")

    arguments = [
        rate_arg,
        device_arg,
    ]

    default_parameters = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory(package_name),
        'config',
        param_name
        )
    
    override_parameters = {
        'output_rate': LaunchConfiguration('rate'),
        'spi_dev': LaunchConfiguration('device'),
    }
    
    imu = Node(
            package=package_name,
            executable='imu_node',
            name='imu',
            parameters=[default_parameters, override_parameters],
            output='screen',
            emulate_tty=True
        )

    return LaunchDescription([
       *arguments,
       imu
    ])
```

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: This works if i use ``/**`` in the .yaml params file instead of ``/imu``. What if I have multiple parameters for different node in the same yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by declaring the node in the global namespace `/`:

```py
imu = Node(
            package=package_name,
            executable='imu_node',
            name='imu',
            namespace='/', # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            parameters=[default_parameters, override_parameters],
            output='screen',
            emulate_tty=True
        )
```

In this way, ros parameters are resolved correctly without any modification or namespace prefix on parameters declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You want to ensure that the override parameters are in the same namespace as the node:

```
override_parameters = {
    '/imu/output_rate': LaunchConfiguration('rate'),
    '/imu/spi_dev': LaunchConfiguration('device'),
}
```

Then, when creating the node, **explicitly set the namespace** to ensure all parameters are correctly scoped

```
imu = Node(
    package=package_name,
    executable='imu_node',
    namespace='imu',
    name='imu',
    parameters=[default_parameters, override_parameters],
    output='screen',
    emulate_tty=True
)
```

Next would be testing your launch file by specifying launch arguments and checking if the parameters in the node are being overridden as expected. Add logging in to your node to print out the parameter values or verify that using the ROS 2 command line.

Comment: This does not work :(

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: simply put, the parameters with namespace are not picked up by the node. Once I set the namespace, it picks up the default ones, while the override are mapped like /imu/output_rate but in a global namespace. It's like feeding two .yaml parameters file to the node, but the default ones are in the correct namespace, the others are in the global namepace, and are named with the imu namespace prefix.

Comment: any suggestion?